# Random Forest with GridSearchCV - Error on param_grid

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

Im trying to create a Random Forest model with GridSearchCV but am getting an error pertaining to param_grid: *"ValueError: Invalid parameter max_features for estimator Pipeline. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()"*. I'm classifying documents so I am also pushing tf-idf vectorizer to the pipeline.
Here is the code:

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, f1_score, accuracy_score, precision_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

 #Classifier Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())
])
# Params for classifier
params = {"max_depth": [3, None],
              "max_features": [1, 3, 10],
              "min_samples_split": [1, 3, 10],
              "min_samples_leaf": [1, 3, 10],
              # "bootstrap": [True, False],
              "criterion": ["gini", "entropy"]}

# Grid Search Execute
rf_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipeline , param_grid=params) #cv=10
rf_detector = rf_grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print(rf_grid.grid_scores_)
```

I can't figure out why the error is showing. The same btw is occurring when I run a decision tree with GridSearchCV. (Scikit-learn 0.17)

Answer (score 36):

You have to assign the parameters to the named step in the pipeline.  In your case `classifier`.  Try prepending  `classifier__` to the parameter name.  [Sample pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html)

```
params = {"classifier__max_depth": [3, None],
              "classifier__max_features": [1, 3, 10],
              "classifier__min_samples_split": [1, 3, 10],
              "classifier__min_samples_leaf": [1, 3, 10],
              # "bootstrap": [True, False],
              "classifier__criterion": ["gini", "entropy"]}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works! Makes sense, I wasn't aware of this

Answer (score 21):

Try to run [`get_params()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.get_params) on your **final** pipeline object, not just the estimator. This way it'd generate **all** available pipe-items **unique** keys for the grid parameters.

```
sorted(pipeline.get_params().keys())
```

['classifier',
 'classifier__bootstrap',
 'classifier__class_weight',
 'classifier__criterion',
 'classifier__max_depth',
 **'classifier__max_features',**
 'classifier__max_leaf_nodes',
 'classifier__min_impurity_split',
 'classifier__min_samples_leaf',
 'classifier__min_samples_split',
 'classifier__min_weight_fraction_leaf',
 'classifier__n_estimators',
 'classifier__n_jobs',
 'classifier__oob_score',
 'classifier__random_state',
 'classifier__verbose',
 'classifier__warm_start',
 'steps',
 'tfidf',
 'tfidf__analyzer',
 'tfidf__binary',
 'tfidf__decode_error',
 'tfidf__dtype',
 'tfidf__encoding',
 'tfidf__input',
 'tfidf__lowercase',
 'tfidf__max_df',
 'tfidf__max_features',
 'tfidf__min_df',
 'tfidf__ngram_range',
 'tfidf__norm',
 'tfidf__preprocessor',
 'tfidf__smooth_idf',
 'tfidf__stop_words',
 'tfidf__strip_accents',
 'tfidf__sublinear_tf',
 'tfidf__token_pattern',
 'tfidf__tokenizer',
 'tfidf__use_idf',
 'tfidf__vocabulary']

This is especially useful when you're using the short [`make_pipeline()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html) syntax for Piplines, where you don't bother with labels for pipe items:

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), RandomForestClassifier())
sorted(pipeline.get_params().keys())
```

['randomforestclassifier',
 'randomforestclassifier__bootstrap',
 'randomforestclassifier__class_weight',
 'randomforestclassifier__criterion',
 'randomforestclassifier__max_depth',
 **'randomforestclassifier__max_features',**
 'randomforestclassifier__max_leaf_nodes',
 'randomforestclassifier__min_impurity_split',
 'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_leaf',
 'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_split',
 'randomforestclassifier__min_weight_fraction_leaf',
 'randomforestclassifier__n_estimators',
 'randomforestclassifier__n_jobs',
 'randomforestclassifier__oob_score',
 'randomforestclassifier__random_state',
 'randomforestclassifier__verbose',
 'randomforestclassifier__warm_start',
 'steps',
 'tfidfvectorizer',
 'tfidfvectorizer__analyzer',
 'tfidfvectorizer__binary',
 'tfidfvectorizer__decode_error',
 'tfidfvectorizer__dtype',
 'tfidfvectorizer__encoding',
 'tfidfvectorizer__input',
 'tfidfvectorizer__lowercase',
 'tfidfvectorizer__max_df',
 'tfidfvectorizer__max_features',
 'tfidfvectorizer__min_df',
 'tfidfvectorizer__ngram_range',
 'tfidfvectorizer__norm',
 'tfidfvectorizer__preprocessor',
 'tfidfvectorizer__smooth_idf',
 'tfidfvectorizer__stop_words',
 'tfidfvectorizer__strip_accents',
 'tfidfvectorizer__sublinear_tf',
 'tfidfvectorizer__token_pattern',
 'tfidfvectorizer__tokenizer',
 'tfidfvectorizer__use_idf',
 'tfidfvectorizer__vocabulary']

Comment: Perfect.  Adding "classifier__" as the previous answer mentioned still produced the error for me.  I needed to find all the params using (get_params) and saw I needed to preface each parameter with "randomforestclassifier__". Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with randomizedsearchcv, so I adjusted verbose parameter, and got the result

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30736783)